# MySQL errors: 1146 and 1051

Tags: mysql, administration

Am a Newbie to MySql
when I tried to do the backup its throwing me an error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: 
Table doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

when i tried to drop that problem table it throws me an

```
error 1051 mysql
unable to drop the table.
```

I've tried everything, but doesnt work.

As it is still in the development stage,
I've decided to drop that troubled Database and create new One.

Can't do this also.

Can anyone, please, help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the .frm .myi and .myd files of the following table.. if the table is using MyISAM storage engine or  .frm and .ibd files if table is using InnoDB storage engine

Answer (score 0):

it explains. the table does not exist. Have you selected the active database schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to **DROP** this table and then create again (sometimes it helps). Also try to repair the database via **mysqlcheck**.

Comment: the second error message clearly states `unable to drop the table.`